# Silent Local Notifications

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, push-notification, broadcast

Is it possible to broadcast a local Push Notification in one class of the app and receive and handle it in another class in iOS like android does with Intents and Broadcast-receiver?!

And i don´t want to let the User know. The Basic principal of that what i want is to broadcast a "job". Another class should receive all Broadcast and handle those...

In my AppDelegate I already have this method:

```
 -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {

}
```

Is there any way to do this in iOS 7?!

Comment: This is not what `UILocalNotification` are for, as @BilalSaifudeen link suggest use `UINotificationCenter` for this.

Comment: If this question is now un-needed, please delete it. Thanks!

Comment: Why delete?! If other users will search exactly the same they will find my Question and the answer ;)